# Removing empty space before "/" in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

I have the string: `"udlejning-as /8497"` in a DataFrame, and I am trying to remove the empty space before the `"/"`, but `pd.replace` and `pd[].str.strip` does not work... any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
import re
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

firms = pd.DataFrame({
    'url':[
        'https://cvrapi.dk/virksomhed/dk/Haki-AS/89391814;',
        'https://cvrapi.dk/virksomhed/dk/Nordsjaellands-Stilladser-ApS/87199215;',
        'https://cvrapi.dk/virksomhed/dk/Zarges ApS /87147010;',
        'https://cvrapi.dk/virksomhed/dk/Poulsen Stillads og Liftudlejning AS /84977217;'
    ]})

print(firms)

firms['url'] = firms['url'].str.lower()

firms['url'] = firms.replace({'url':{
    'æ': 'ae',
    'ø': 'oe',
    'å': 'aa',
    ' ;': ';',
    ', ': ',',
    ' /': '/)',
    ' ': '-'
}}, regex=True)

firms['url'] = firms['url'].str.replace(' /', '/')
firms.replace(' /', '/', regex=True)

print('-------')
print(firms['url'])
```

None of the below mentioned solutions seems to work as I get this output:

```
0    https://cvrapi.dk/virksomhed/dk/haki-as/89391814;                              
1    https://cvrapi.dk/virksomhed/dk/nordsjaellands-stilladser-aps/87199215;        
2    https://cvrapi.dk/virksomhed/dk/zarges-aps /87147010;                          
3    https://cvrapi.dk/virksomhed/dk/poulsen-stillads-og-liftudlejning-as /84977217;
```

with errors in row 2 and 3

Answer (score 3):

```
dfr.colname = dfr.colname.str.replace(' /', '/')
```

Comment: I tried outside of the DataFrame and it works, but inside it does not at least not when i try this:

firms.urls = firms.url.str.replace(' /', '/')
or
firms['url'] = firms['url'].str.replace(' /', '/')

Answer (score 2):

Generally:

```
s = "udlejning-as /8497"
s.replace(' /', '/')
```

For dataframe it would be like:

```
df.col.str.replace(' /', '/')
```

For replacing across all values in dataframe:

```
df.replace(' /', '/', regex=True)
```

Comment: It's a `pandas.Dataframe`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Add in your code

```
' ': '/',
```

Comment: It's a `pandas.Dataframe`.